# Odd Behavior of Delete

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, vote-to-delete

I have seen this many times. *This* time, I'm going to write it down and ask.

1. Use the 10k tools, ["Deleted" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=)
2. See an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989518/dont-want-to-login-again-and-again-android/20989950#20989950) I may want to vote to delete.
   It shows has having 2 delete votes.
   [image]
3. Click the link. The answer shows no delete votes.
   [image]
4. Downvote the answer. It only shows the downvote.
   [image]
5. Refresh the page. Now I can see the 2 delete votes.
   [image]
6. Vote to delete it. Now it's deleted.
   [image]

So, what's up with that?

Comment: Note the score requirement for an answer. The score must be -1 or lower. An answer at score -1 can be upvoted to score 0 and no longer have a delete link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "delete" link is only shown when the post has a negative score. Therefore if the post has a non-negative score you won't see the delete link or the number of delete votes against the post.

The existing delete votes against the post would have been added through the review queues - clicking on the "delete" button (which is only available to users with 20k+ reputation, this button is labelled as "recommend deletion" for all other users and this doesn't cast a delete vote) when reviewing low quality answers is one such way to cast a delete vote on a post before it has negative votes.

Comment: If the post has a *nonnegative score* you won't see it. If there are 0 votes on it, the score is 0 too, but if the net score is positive it doesn't matter how many downvotes are on it as long as the upvotes cancel them out.

Comment: Yep - that's what I meant - changed my wording. Could have read my original wording as net score

Comment: Not true. From the low quality queue it's not a real delete vote, dunno how it's called but it needs 6 such votes to delete and it's separate from the 20K votes. The number near delete link is only real delete votes cast by 20K users.

Comment: Yeah, that's what's confusing. It acts like it had 2 "real" delete votes on it before I got there, because 1. Downvoting showed 2 delete votes, and 2. Voting to delete deleted it (as though my delete vote was vote #3)

Comment: @ShadowWizard if that was the case, why would "Delete" change to "Recommend Deletion" if I run out of delete votes? Casting a delete vote from the review queue as a 20k+ user will put a delete vote on the post

Comment: @Flyk the "as a 20k+ user" is missing from your answer and is critical part. :)

Comment: That's covered by stating "delete" rather than "recommend deletion" I would have expected. The button is labelled differently depending on reputation level. I have added the text "as a 20k+ user" to remove the ambiguity and clarify the original wording I used.

Comment: Have you confirmed that this was the sequence of events for this particular answer, or are you being general?

Comment: Your screenshots seem to indicate this is the case, I do not have enough reputation on SO to do all of the required checking but if you check http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history you should be able to see that multiple users (two in this instance) chose to delete (not recommend deletion) the post in question. If you don't see two users deleting the question in this manner, it's possible that @ShadowWizard's proposed solution is the case - which is a little harder to test in the instance that a downvote was removed from the post

Comment: @JohnSaunders yes, it's confirmed beyond a doubt now. See [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0X5TP.png). ([link to review item](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3754685))

Comment: Worth to mention that if that single user wouldn't have closed the item by "Looking good", three more "Recommend Deletion" would have also deleted the answer, without a third actual delete vote.

Answer (score 3):

In your specific case, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20989950/447356) [reached the low quality review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3754685) (probably automatically due to being link ony) and two 20K users cast delete vote while it had score of 0, as Flyk already explains [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215361/152859).

I will add my own two cents, for the common scenario of answers that do not reach the low quality review queue. This is what happens with such answers:

1. The answer is posted.
2. The answer receives a downvote.
3. 20K+ user(s) vote to delete the answer.
4. The answer receives an upvote and reach score of 0.

Ordinary users can't delete the answer anymore and it's grayed out in the 10K tools. However, the delete vote(s) are still there.

When someone now cast another downvote, it's making the answer -1 and 20K'ers can vote again.

The downvote AJAX action does not reload the whole answer with all actions by design, same way that inline editing of a question won't update the tags in the sidebar to the right... for those things just reload the page.

Comment: Have you confirmed this sequence of steps, for this particular answer?

Comment: @JohnSaunders actually, on the specific answer you mentioned Flyk is right and low quality queue is involved. Will think what to do with my answer, it's still true in general.

Comment: Done, made my answer more generic.