# Please Improve the Experience for "Deleters"

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, vote-to-delete

This is related to my question, "[Odd Behavior of Delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215360/odd-behavior-of-delete). In that question, I asked about a confusing user interface for deleting a particular answer.

In *this* question, I'm going to rant a little.

---

Please change the experience of deletion in the 10k tools.

1. If the answer has no downvotes, then don't show the "delete" link. That's ok, it's as is today.
2. But if the answer (or question) already has delete votes, then please continue to show the "delete" link, and allow me to vote to delete it. Since it already has delete votes, I shouldn't have to downvote before I'm allowed to delete it.
3. The styles for the different categories of post are very difficult for me to distinguish with my old person's eyes. Please make them more distinct. (Young folks: this will be *you* one day - don't scoff)
4. Maybe add some sort of (i) information icon which has a tooltip saying, in English, what the category is, like "answer with delete votes, but it has a zero score so you can't vote to delete it until you downvote"

Comment: I'm disappointed by how reasonable this rant sounds

Comment: regarding #2, I think the reason it's hidden is so that posts that have just been improved (via edits or whatever) and subsequently upvoted don't get deleted just because there are multiple delete votes already present on the post. While in the exception that is the instance in "Odd Behavior of Delete" this worked against the person deleting, deleting a post that had just been improves works against the user experience of the user who had spent time improving the post - which is a greater evil IMO

Comment: I would vote in this case to show a "delete if you really want to, but the post has been improved, so maybe don't delete" link instead of just a "delete" link. Basically, "don't lie to me" in order to change my behavior. Ask nicely, and maybe I'll change my behavior.

Comment: Only one thing here is flawed: suppose someone post bad answer. It's downvoted and get a delete vote. Then the answer is edited, improved, and get upvotes. There is no reason to let us vote to delete it again. Other than that, it's all making sense in my opinion. :)

Comment: The only exception to my above comment may be answer that reach the low quality queue... for such answers it will make sense to show the delete link regardless of its score (even when positive) as it can be voted on from within the review queue. And when the review is complete, back to the ordinary rules.

Comment: instead of hiding the delete button, gray it out, so you can see they were there, but the post is no longer eligible to be deleted.

Comment: @RichardTingle: I'm practicing "constructive ranting".